# Перезаписывается массив

Tags: php, массивы

Друзья, в каждом `if` массив почему то перезаписывается. Сразу скажу, что условия оба выполняются. В массив пишется соответственно инфа только из второго условия, точнее перезаписывает инфу из первого. В первом условии пишется, потому что если за комментировать второе, то массив заполняется

```
for ($i=0; $i < 4 ; $i++) { 
if ($value_filter->like == 1) {
    $action = $value_filter->action; //действия на аккаунт
    $param = array("username" => $username,
                    "password" => $password,
                    "method" => 'like', //Что будем делать с данной задачей
                    "order" => $value_search->media_id, //Цель
                    "cookie" => '0');
}
if ($value_filter->follow == 1) {
    $expld = explode("_", $value_search->media_id);
    $action = $value_filter->action; //действия на аккаунт
    $param = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password,
                                "method" => 'follow', //Что будем делать с данной задачей
                                "order" => $expld[1], //Цель
                                "cookie" => '0'); 
}
```

}
    var_dump($param);

Comment: и? вроде все логично, если выполняются оба условия. Что вызывает ваше удивление/негодование то? Код в полной мере соответствует тому, что вы описываете.

Comment: так а что вы хотите, чтобы массив всегда дополнялся новыми данными? Или что?

Comment: Объявите `$param` массивом, это сейчас переменная, которая, естественно, перезаписывается. Причем в каждой итерации цикла он должен заполняться по идее, иначе зачем вообще цикл? `$param[$i]`. К тому же можно писать `if ($value_filter->follow) {`, если у Вас идет проверка на **true/false**.

Comment: @DaemonHK спасибо, понял. По поводу if, то там всё верно, нужно именно на единицу смотреть, ибо есть множество других значений ещё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите чтобы выполнялось одно из условий, используйте конструкцию

```
if ($value_filter->like == 1) {
    ...
}
elseif ($value_filter->follow == 1) {
    ...
```

Если допустимо выполнение обоих то

```
$param[] = array...
```

Можете ознакомиться с функцией array_push()